# How to add a map as the background of jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, leaflet

EDIT: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anh6y80y/5/)

I have a leaflet map which is created by the html:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

And a jumbotron

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Example Unit</h1>
    <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
</div>
```

with the following style

```
.jumbotron {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: #444 0 1px 1px;
  background:transparent;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-bottom:0; 
}
```

How do I make the map as the background of the jumbotron?

EDIT:

the css

```
#map { height: 180px; }
```

the js

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([38.578, -77.243], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/MapID/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: have you tried adding `id="map"` to the `jumbotron` div?

Comment: ...and do you have details on the map? i'm guessing it's some js / jquery script?

Comment: @webeno the problem is the map is displayed first, and the rest of the text is displayed after that. I am adding the rest of the code.

Comment: let me know when you added the code, it's very difficult to help you this way...

Comment: @webeno done. I'll try to figure out jsfiddle and put it there too meanwhile.

Comment: definitely looks better now...

Comment: @webeno also check the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/anh6y80y/ the map won't display because i've removed my key but the effect should be clear from its scaffolding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63646/discussion-between-webeno-and-yayu).

Answer (score 0):

Now it got the solution: I set the  height and marginBottom of the mapDiv with javascript and add position:relative;

JS

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([38.578, -77.243], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapid/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);

var height=document.querySelector('.jumbotron').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('map').style.height=height+"px";
document.getElementById('map').style.marginBottom="-"+height+"px";
```

CSS

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}

.jumbotron {
          color: white;
          text-shadow: #444 0 1px 1px;
          background:transparent;
          background-size: 100%;
          margin-bottom:0; 
             overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
        }
        .navbar {margin-bottom:0; }
        #map { height: 0px; 
margin:-30px -30px -0px -30px;
    z-index:0;

}
.jumbotron h1,.jumbotron p
{
    z-index:100;
    position:relative;

}
```